# How to apply classes to images that are automatically generated at run time through js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is the Html I can see in the browser

```
<div id="mygallery-paginate"> 
    <img src="images/opencircle.png"   data-index="0" data-moveto="0" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="images/opencircle.png"   data-index="1" data-moveto="1" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="images/closedcircle.png" data-index="2" data-moveto="2" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="images/opencircle.png"   data-index="3" data-moveto="3" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="images/opencircle.png"   data-index="4" data-moveto="4" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
</div>
```

I want like this

```
<div id="mygallery-paginate"> 
    <img src="images/opencircle.png"   class="one" data-index="0" data-moveto="0" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="images/opencircle.png"   class="two" data-index="1" data-moveto="1" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="images/closedcircle.png" class="three" data-index="2" data-moveto="2" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="images/opencircle.png"   class="four" data-index="3" data-moveto="3" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="images/opencircle.png"   class="five" data-index="4" data-moveto="4" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
</div>
```

Please suggest with neccessary CSS/JS

Comment: are there any rules for the class name and/or where is the source of the class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/35phe/)

```
var nclasses = ['one','two','three','four','five'];
$('#mygallery-paginate').find('img').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass(nclasses[i]);
});
```

Comment: wow that's awesome!!! Hi @roasted I am looking for this kind of answer many thanks

Comment: It's not better than YD1m's answer. You should be more specific on how do you generate new images? Providing sample code would be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var classes = ['one', 'two', 'free']; // add more if need
var i = 0;

$('#mygallery-paginate img').each(function(){
     if(!!classes[i++])
         $(this).addClass(classes[i]);
});
```

Comment: this, but would recommand to use other classnames, like "image1, image2, image3, ..." instead of "one, two, three, ...". would be easier and more scalable

Comment: Hi @YD1m  but these are dynamically generated images can we able to add classes like this

Comment: @Thejdeep: maybe you should specify your requirement more clearly

Answer (score 0):

What do you refer with "apply classes to images"? Secuential numbering for each element?

Comment: no i want to add some different css properties for for different images

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, this is an attempt to ask OP for clarification. Soon, when you'll have 50 reputation points you'll be able to post comments on questions. Until then please kindly avoid in posting answers asking for clarification. Your answer does not attempt to answer the question and generates clutter for moderators. Thanks a lot for the effort though - it's appreciated!